# Porqué me sale error no puedo identificarlo en imagen mostrado en mi consulta alguien me ayuda por favor

Tags: c#, linq

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ESTE ES MI CODIGO

```
 public ComprarBloqueosBusqueda BuscaPorNombre(int? id)
    {
        ComprarBloqueosBusqueda vCOMBLO_Comprar = new ComprarBloqueosBusqueda();
        var result = from BLO in contexto.Bloqueo
                     from EXC in contexto.Excursion
                     where
                       BLO.BloqueosId == id &&
                        (from BloExc in contexto.BloqueoExcursion
                         where
                           BloExc.BLE_BloqueoID == id &&
                         from EXC in contexto.Excursion
                         .GroupBy(e => e.ExcursionesId)
                         .ToList()
                         .Select(eg => new
                         {
                             BloExc.BLE_ExcursionId,
                             ExcursionesId = eg.Key,
                             EXC_ = string.Join(",", eg.Select(ex => ex.EXC_Nombre))
                         })).Contains(new { BLE_ExcursionId = EXC.ExcursionesId });

                    var lComBloquepsNom = result.ToList();
                    foreach (var datos in lComBloquepsNom)
                    {
                        vCOMBLO_Comprar.BloqueosId = datos.ExcursionesId;
                        vCOMBLO_Comprar.excursiones = string.Join(",", result.Select(ex => ex.EXC_Nombre));
                    }
                    return vCOMBLO_Comprar;
                }
```

ESTOS SON MIS TABLAS 
TABLA EXCURSIONES:
ExcursionesId  EXC_Nombre
2                 TANGOL
3                  ESTADIO
4                  VISITA
5                   PLAZA
7                   PAMPA
8                   MADRID
21                  COSTA
22                  PASEO

TABLA Bloqueos:
BloqueosId  BLO_Nombre
1             Visia
2             Paseo
3             Visita2

Tabla BloqueoExcursion:
BloqueoExcursionId BLE_ExcursionId  BLE_BloqueoID 
4                     21                89
5                      4                45
8                       7               23

Answer (score 1):

No deberias armar dentro del `where` de linq un nuevo filtro

Intente acomodar un poco la query linq

```
var result = from BLO in contexto.Bloqueo
             from EXC in contexto.Excursion
             from BloExc in contexto.BloqueoExcursion
             where BLO.BloqueosId == id && BloExc.BLE_BloqueoID == id
             group EXC by EXC.ExcursionesId into eg
             select new
                 {
                     BLE_ExcursionId = BloExc.BLE_ExcursionId,
                     ExcursionesId = eg.Key,
                     EXC_ = string.Join(",", eg.Select(ex => ex.EXC_Nombre))
                 };
```

la idea es definir las tablas que consultas, luego filtras y agrupas. Seria bueno no mezclar la sintaxis entre query de linq y metodos de extension porque se hace complejo de seguir, usa una misma tecnica

Ademas recomendaria que definas el `join` de linq para relacionar las tablas de alguna forma

[join (Cláusula, Referencia de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause)

No estoy seguro como juega el `Contains()`

[Realizar combinaciones agrupadas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-grouped-joins)

Comment: en el group y en el select no acepta ("e"------"BloExc"),  me dice no existe en el contexto actual

Comment: edite el ejemplo, cambien el group by, pero no veo en el select donde se usa "e"

Comment: Disculpa si esta bien "e" no hay.  Me podrias ayudar por fa soy principiante  el "BloExc" para que no me sale error que tengo que hacer

Comment: que dice el mensaje de error? intentaste poniendo otro nombre como ser BE

Comment: Si me dice que  no existe en el contexto actual "BloExc"

Comment: si entiendo, es en el select ya que al estar agrupando no puedes acceder a los alias de las otras tablas. El tema es que deberias aplicar un join entre las tablas, lo que se conoce como group join, edite la respuesta con un link que explica sobre el tema, analiza el ejemplo a ver sino es eso lo que necesitas, pero remarco que tienes que poder relacionar las tablas por algun campo para que funcione

Comment: var result = from BLO in contexto.Bloqueo
 from BloExc in contexto.BloqueoExcursion
where BLO.BloqueosId == id && BloExc.BLE_BloqueoID == id                         
 join  EXC in contexto.Excursion on
BloExc.BLE_ExcursionId equals EXC.ExcursionesId into eg  
                         select new
                          {
                          BLE_ExcursionId = BloExc.BLE_ExcursionId,  
                          ExcursionesId = eg.Key,
                          EXC_Nombre = string.Join<string>(",", eg.Select(ex => ex.EXC_Nombre))
                         };

Comment: Ya le hice Join pero ahora ya me sale error en  "eg.Key"

Comment: pero no se usa key cuando usas el join ya que el propio "eg" contiene las coincidencias, no es una agrupado. Si lesite la documentacion del link veras que en "eg" tendras todos los Excursion que coincidan con BloqueoExcursion, pero no sera un unico valor o si depende, en este caso como es una union por id puede serlo, quizas usando ExcursionesId = eg.First().ExcursionesId

Comment: Chvre ya no me sale error. Ahora el problema esta al ejecutar mi aplicacion me muestra este mensaje  //////// Información adicional: LINQ to Entities no reconoce el método 'System.String Join(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])' del método, y este método no se puede convertir en una expresión de almacenamiento. ///////////////  me dice que LINQ no reconoce el metodo string