# Problema con consulta linq Me dice que, LINQ to Entities no reconoce el método 'System.String Join(System.String, System.Collections

Tags: c#, linq

```
    public ComprarBloqueosBusqueda BuscaPorNombre(int? id){
        ComprarBloqueosBusqueda vCOMBLO_Comprar = new ComprarBloqueosBusqueda();
        var result = from BLO in contexto.Bloqueo                             
                     from BloExc in contexto.BloqueoExcursion
                     where BLO.BloqueosId == id && BloExc.BLE_BloqueoID == id
                     join EXC in contexto.Excursion on                            
                        BloExc.BLE_ExcursionId equals EXC.ExcursionesId into eg
                     select new 
                        {
                            BLE_ExcursionId = BloExc.BLE_ExcursionId,
                          //ExcursionesId = eg.First().ExcursionesId,
                            ExcursionesId = eg.FirstOrDefault().ExcursionesId,
                            EXC_Nombre = string.Join(",", eg.Select(ex => ex.EXC_Nombre))                              
                    };
           var lComBloquepsNom = result.ToList();
                        foreach (var datos in lComBloquepsNom)
                        {
                            vCOMBLO_Comprar.BloqueosId = datos.ExcursionesId;
                            vCOMBLO_Comprar.excursiones = string.Join(",", result.Select(ex => ex.EXC_Nombre));
                        }
                        return vCOMBLO_Comprar;
                    }
```

Comment: Hola M Mario. Ya has publicado [esa pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106094/porqu%C3%A9-me-sale-error-no-puedo-identificarlo-en-imagen-mostrado-en-mi-consulta-al). Por favor, edita para mejorar la original en vez de hacer otra. Un saludo

Comment: si, lo que pasa es que ya lo solucioné lo que tenía problema en el anterior pregunta

Comment: Entonces has de marcar la otra como aceptada (si es que fue la respuesta lo que te ayudó. Si no, publica tu propia respuesta siguiendo [answer]). Entonces esta es una pregunta nueva?  Intenta explicarlo mejor siguiendo [ask]. Un saludo

Comment: Así es, es nueva pregunta  ok gracias por explicarme

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que utilizas `Entity Framework` el cual transforma el linq en sql y ese Join del string no puede convertirlo.
Deberias ejecutar la query para luego aplicar el join del string

```
var result = (from BLO in contexto.Bloqueo                             
                 from BloExc in contexto.BloqueoExcursion
                 where BLO.BloqueosId == id && BloExc.BLE_BloqueoID == id
                 join EXC in contexto.Excursion on                            
                    BloExc.BLE_ExcursionId equals EXC.ExcursionesId into eg
                select new 
                {
                    BLE_ExcursionId = BloExc.BLE_ExcursionId,

                    ExcursionesId = eg.FirstOrDefault().ExcursionesId,
                    EXC_NombreList = eg.Select(ex => ex.EXC_Nombre),
                    EXC_Nombre = ""                 
                }).Tolist();

result.ForEach(x=> x.EXC_Nombre = string.Join(",", x.EXC_NombreList));
```

como veras la primer query se ejecuta al realizar el `ToList()` para despues una vez ejecutado el sql que genero `entity framework` poder unir la lista separada por coma

Comment: En }).Tolist(); sale error y me dice esto:                    'IQueryable<<anonymous type:'int BLE_ExcursionId, int ExcursionesId IEnumerable<string>EXC_NombreList
                , string EXC_Nombre >>' no contiene una definicio pata ToList' ni se encuentra ningun metodo 
                de extension 'ToList' que acepta un primer argumento de tipo 'IQueryable<<anonymous type:'int BLE_ExcursionId, int ExcursionesId IEnumerable<string> EXC_NombreList
                , string EXC_Nombre >>'

Comment: estas cerrando correctamente los (), recuerda que engloba toda la query, alli equivoque pero es ToList() o sea la L va en mayusculas

Comment: Si ya lo corregí gracias, ahora me sale error en  ForEach(x => x.EXC_Nombre   Y me dice                string 'a.EXC_Nombre(get;)    
                    Tipos anónimos:
                   'a new {int BLE_ExcursionId, int ExcursionesId , IEnumerable<string>EXC_NombreList, string EXC_Nombre}
                    No se puede asignar a la propiedad o el indizador '< anonymous type:
                int BLE_ExcursionId, int ExcursionesId IEnumerable<string> EXC_NombreList , 
                    string EXC_Nombre>.EXC_Nombre' Porque es solo de lectura

Comment: Me podrías ayudar por favor Leandro TuttinI , a me pase dias con esto

Comment: me parece que los tipos anonimos definen las propiedades como solo lectura, tiene que ser una clase anonima la que utilices, o podrias definir una clase concreta? o sea apunto a no usar el new el select de linq, sino una clase

Comment: /* 
             Leandro Tuttini si lo logre enterderlo lo que me dijiste lo que pasa es
             en el Select le estoy haciendo consulta a 2 tablas y me sale error 
             */

Comment: @MMarioMandzukicMarioMandzu no debes editar la respuesta, si quieres agregar informacion, agregala a la pregunta. tu edicion fue rechazada.